# PostgreSQL using json_populate_recordset without pre-defined type

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to use `json_populate_recordset` function in `plpgsql`. Everything works fine when the `x` is a custom type or table type. But is it possible to use it with something like cusom tyoe definer in execution time? Like we use in CTEs
`WITH cte (a int, b int4)`?

Comment: Tested on PostgreSQL 9.5: `select * from json_populate_recordset((0,0), '[{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":3,"b":4}]') as t(a int, b int)`

Comment: @Abelisto thx a lot, worked for me!